# Google Maps API not showing (fixed height / width does not solve)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Showing the map was working before but for some reason I can't really figure it stopped working.

Here is my html inclusion:

```
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=THIS_KEY_IS_CORRECT">
  </script>
```

And here is my html:

```
(with style tags)
#map { height: 500px; }

<div id="map" > </div>
```

And my javascript

```
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Running init map");
            var map_div = document.getElementById("map");
            var map_handler = new google.maps.Map(map_div, map_options);
            console.log(map_handler);
        },2000);
```

Here is the console log of `map_handler`:

`ug {__gm: Yf, W: undefined, mapTypes: Object, features: Object, overlayMapTypes: _.td…}`

So `map_handler` is actually returning something.

As I said, **this used to work**. For some reason it does not anymore.

Any idea why?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is `map_options`?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't the primary source of your issue - please note that you can't rely on `setTimeout` to tell you when the google maps JS API has been loaded. Use a callback:

```
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=THIS_KEY_IS_CORRECT&callback=myMapIsReady">
  </script>
```

And then

```
<script>

 var myMapIsReady = function() {
            console.log("Running init map");
            var map_div = document.getElementById("map");
            var map_handler = new google.maps.Map(map_div, map_options);
            console.log(map_handler);  
 };

</script>
```

Here's the question, why are you saying this isn't working? **How** is it not working? What do you see on your screen?

A hint might be what is `map_options` you haven't shown where it is defined and if you init a google map with no center latlng/zoom, you'll just see a grey block.